# Freeze when calling PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices

Tags: java, windows, printing

We have application which look up for printers. In the env(windows 7) it is setup it detects few local printerservices such as XPS writer, one note and few physical printers from network. When the load is high it get freeze and we found that `PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices` is line which get stuck. 
We able to reproduce this by running four apps at same time and `PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices` is the only line those apps had. Main problem is it does not throw any exception or does not have timeouts(windows event log had some timeout logs for that time).
Any of you have experience that type of a problem? Do you see any reasons why it could happens.

```
public class Test
{

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    PrintService[] printServices = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, null);
    System.out.println("Time = "+(System.currentTimeMillis() - time));
  }
}
```

If you run multiples at same time sometimes new reach the sysout(Not that easy to reproduce)

Comment: Could you please provide some example code?

Comment: Have you tried stepping into the lookup method with a debugger?

Comment: No but thread dump says at sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.getAllPrinterNames(Native Method)
 at sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.refreshServices(Unknown Source)
 - locked <10e1204> (a sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup)
 at sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.getPrintServices(Unknown Source)
 - locked <10e1204> (a sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup)
 at sun.print.Win32PrintServiceLookup.getPrintServices(Unknown Source)
 at javax.print.PrintServiceLookup.getServices(Unknown Source)

Comment: This is an issue with the certificate I suspect. What is your os?